# Building ios apk from ionic 3 project

Tags: ios, ionic3, apk

When i try to build : ionic cordova build ios apk, i got this below message . Could u plz help me . Thanks

> cordova build ios
>   (node:18556) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: xcodebuild was not found. Please install version 7.0.0 or greater from App Store
>   (node:18556) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:18556) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

**I have installed everything as follows**

```
[11:41:11]  lint finished in 13.88 s
PS C:\Users\user\myApp> cordova -v
8.0.0
PS C:\Users\user\myApp> java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
PS C:\Users\user\myApp> javac -version
javac 1.8.0_101
PS C:\Users\user\myApp>
```

Comment: are you using windows for development?

Comment: @NitishkumarSingh Yes i am using windows

Comment: On Windows, I don't think there is any direct way. You can go for Ionic Pro or something else

Answer (score 1):

iOS apps are packaged as **.ipa**, not **.apk** which is for Android.

You need Xcode and the iOS SDK to build an iOS **.ipa**.
Unfortunately, both are only available on a Mac.

As explained in the [ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/platform-setup/windows-setup.html), they mention that the only option is to use Ionic Package:

> **iOS**
>   The iOS SDK does not run on Windows, so nothing to do here. Still
>   want to build for iOS, though? Check out [Package](https://ionicframework.com/pro#packaging), part of the Ionic
>   Cloud.

From the [Ionic Package docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/package/):

> **Packaging Native Binaries**
>   Ionic Pro’s Package feature makes it easy to build native app binaries for iOS and Android in the cloud.
>   Perfect for automating binary builds and for developers using Windows
>   that want to build iOS apps.

That's your 1st option.

A 2nd option would be to use a Mac instead as your development environment.
If you're planning to be developing iOS apps long-term, then you really need a Mac.
(You can build Android **.apk**'s on a Mac but not the other way around.)

A 3rd option is to run Mac OS on a virtual machine or setup your own "Hackintosh".
Though, doing some researching will tell you that that's going to be a complicated process in itself, and it's not recommended due to instability issues.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your are trying to create `ipa` file. There is nothing called "`ios apk`".

**You need a macOS machine to create `ipa`**.

`ipa` files can not be created on windows machine.

Comment: Harcker and @Yuvraj Patil . Is there any way to build ios apk from windwos machine ?